# Hide and show divs with multiple common classes

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I'm trying to build a simple interaction, but it turns out it's a little bit tricky and I'm not able to do it.

I want to use some checkboxes to hide and display different divs according to different classes. The classes in the divs are dynamic and the structure of the boxes has to be that way.

Wtih some help I got a working idea, but it has some problems:

https://jsfiddle.net/lanweil/bq8xLxrm/ *code at the end*

1. If you check all checkboxes, and you want to uncheck RED for example, it hides the boxes containing RED elements (class red), but it should hide boxes containing **only** RED. A box with GREEN and RED should still be visible. How could I do this?
2. As a bonus I would like that all the boxes are visible if there is no checkbox checked. I found this that seems quite close, but i couldn't make it work in my case. http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76/

Here is the code for the basic idea, HTML:

```
<ul>
    <label>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tag_checkbox" rel=".box.blue" value="blue" class="tag_checkbox blue" /> <span>BLUE</span>

        </li>
    </label>
    <label>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tag_checkbox" rel=".box.red" value="red" class="tag_checkbox red"> <span>RED</span>

        </li>
    </label>
    <label>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tag_checkbox" rel=".box.green" value="green" class="tag_checkbox green"> <span>GREEN</span>

        </li>
    </label>
    <label>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tag_checkbox" rel=".box.gray" value="gray" class="tag_checkbox gray"> <span>GRAY</span>

        </li>
    </label>
</ul>
<div class="box_container">
    <div class="box blue red green gray"> <span class="blue">BLUE</span><span class="red">RED</span><span class="green">RED</span><span class="gray">GRAY</span>

    </div>
    <div class="box blue green"><span class="blue">BLUE</span><span class="green">GREEN</span>

    </div>
    <div class="box blue"><span class="blue">BLUE</span>

    </div>
    <div class="box red gray"><span class="red">RED</span><span class="gray">GRAY</span>

    </div>
    <div class="box gray"><span class="gray">GRAY</span>

    </div>
    <div class="box blue green gray"><span class="blue">BLUE</span><span class="green">GREEN</span>

    </div>
    <div class="box green gray"><span class="green">GREEN</span><span class="gray">GRAY</span>

    </div>
    <div class="box red"><span class="red">RED</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    /* display: block; */
    display: none;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

span.blue, span.red, span.green, span.gray {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}


span.blue {
    background: lightblue;
}
span.red {
    background: red;
}
span.green {
    background: lightgreen;
}
span.gray {
    background: lightgray;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function (value) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var box = $($this.attr('rel'))

        box.toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function (value) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $($(this).attr("rel")).show();
        } else {
            $($(this).attr("rel")).hide();

            $("input:checked").each(function() {
                $($(this).attr("rel")).show();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When a checkbox is being checked, I am showing all the boxes with the color class it has. After it gets unchecked, first I uncheck the boxes with that color, and after that, I re-show all boxes which have colors from the other checked inputs. This is only the number 1 request.

Working jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bq8xLxrm/24/

Comment: If this was the correct answer, can you please vote-up my answer and click the check mark to mark it as correct answer? Thanks, glad I could help.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot :), any clue of how to make the second point work?